# Simple Site Column Calculation

Tags: calculated-column

I have a calculated Site Column which I want to be some text "PRJ" plus a number from another site column (type number - nothing after the '.') (PRJ-ID - value 00001) in the content type.
I try and Use ="PRJ" &TEXT([PRJ-ID]) but I get an error "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. "
I got the Formula from - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx - combine text and numbers from different columns.

I have been through the previously answered questions, but found nothing.

What have I done wrong ?

Thanks

Nigel

Comment: If I use CONCATENATE("PRJ",[PRJ-ID]) i get an error "The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column."  - The column is there.

Answer (score 0):

The TEXT() function requires a format parameter.

Try `="PRJ"&TEXT([PRJ-ID],"00000")`

Comment: Tried that and got this error - The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

Comment: Try the formula as Excel function, if it works in Excel it will work in SharePoint Calculate Column too

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, like the wrong quotes. I just tried that exact formula that I gave you and it worked fine for me.